# Notepad++ Simple Backup

Tags: notepad++

I lost a file while uploading due to internet disconnection and luckily I had 'Simple Backup' pre-selected. Is there a Notepad++ directory where I can get this file back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the help file, if you didn't specify a custom directory, the backup file should be in the same folder as the original. It should have the same name (including extension) with the `.bak` extension added on.

Comment: same folder as original you mean in the remote server or local server?

Comment: @Jae Usually, it'll be whichever machine you're running Notepad++ on. If you opened the file from a remote location, it might be there instead, so I'd check both.

Comment: I actually found backup under cache!!! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: You found the backup in the cache since that's where the remote file was loaded to in order for Notepad++ to access it.

Answer (score 2):

By default NPP save in the appdata folder: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup`

Steps:

```
1 ShortCut : windowsKey + R
2 Type: %appdata%
3 Then go on \Notepad++\backup
4 Look for your file
5 Enjoys
```